# Extract Max single upper character from table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have test input table

```
-----------------------
RN | IDs
1  | Az
2  | Azz
3  | B
4  | C
5  | a
6  | e
--------------------
```

I need Output

```
----------
RN | IDs
4  |  C
```

I need to get Id which is in UPPER case and single(length 1) also that ID should max in sequence. Like in this example **C** is the **output**.
Because Size is 1 , case is UPPER and MAX in sequence.
Can you please help me here.

Comment: Are you looking for the max RN for rows that include an upper case character? Or the RN of the row that contains the maximum upper case character? What should be the result if you include ( 0, 'Z' ) in your table?

Answer (score 2):

The first step is identifying the `ids` values you want to consider. One way it to check the length and the character range:

```
where length(ids) = 1
and ids between 'A' and 'Z'
```

which makes some assumptions about your character set, or use a regular expression which also makes some assumptions:

```
where regexp_like(ids, '^[A-Z]$')
```

or preferably one which doesn't, using a class instead of a fixed range:

```
where regexp_like(ids, '^[[:upper:]]$')
```

With your data any of those give you two rows, for B and C.

You then need to find the row with the maximum `ids` value. You could do a self-join which is a bit wasteful; or use a subquery that calculates a ranking column and then filter on that:

```
select rn, ids
from (
  select rn, ids, rank() over (order by ids desc) as rnk
  from your_table
  where regexp_like(ids, '^[[:upper:]]$')
)
where rnk = 1;

        RN IDS
---------- ---
         4 C
```

or you could use a variant of the `max()` function with `last` to do it in one step:

```
select max(rn) keep (dense_rank last order by IDs) as rn, max(ids)
from your_table
where regexp_like(ids, '^[[:upper:]]$');

        RN MAX
---------- ---
         4 C
```

You haven't said what should happen if there is a tie, e.g. two `rn` values with `C`. The first of those approaches will show you both - but could be modified to only show one, if you can specify which you want to see. The second will only show you one, and which is indeterminate at the moment as there is no information in the `order by` on how to break the tie.

Comment: This 'regexp_like(ids, '^[[:upper:]]$')'   Worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASCII Function

```
select max(RN) as MAX_ID from yourTableName t1
where length(t1.IDs)=1 and  ascii(IDs)  between ascii('A') and  ascii('Z');
```

Comment: There are thousands of records. I cant do hard coding .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(RN) FROM test
WHERE LENGTH(ID)=1 AND (UNICODE(ID) != UNICODE(LOWER(ID))
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way, enjoy :)

```
select h.ID, h.DESC
  from test_table h
 where length(h.DESC) = 1
   and upper(h.DESC) = h.DESC
   and h.ID = (select MAX(y.ID)
                 from test_table y
                where length(y.DESC) = 1
                  and upper(y.DESC) = y.DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to filter out `length(IDs)=1` firstly, and ordering with respect to `decode(upper(IDs),IDs,0,1), IDs desc`

```
select RN , IDs 
  from
    (   
     select t.*,
            row_number() over (order by decode(upper(IDs),IDs,0,1), IDs desc )
            as rn2
       from t
      where length(IDs)=1   
    ) 
 where rn2 = 1;

 RN      IDS
 -----   -----
  4        C
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/MLYB19930)